# htaccess request forwarding if internal ip

Tags: php, .htaccess, forwarding

Is there a possible htaccess directive that can transparently forward request from index.php to index_internal.php if the request is coming from an internal ip range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.15\.
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index_internal.php [R,NC,QSA,L]
```

What this does:

start mod_rewrite engine (you may have that already)

if (client IP address starts with "192.168.1." [or]

client IP address starts with "10.15.")

and page name is index.php ([n]ot [c]ase sensitive), [r]edirect to index_internal.php, [q]uery [s]tring [a]ppend (i.e. `index.php?foo=bar` becomes `index_internal.php?foo=bar`), [l]eave processing.

Modify as needed for IP address blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it (obviously change the IP address to match your network):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.
RewriteRule index.php index_internal.php
```

If you want an actual header then make it `RewriteRule index.php index_internal.php [L,R,QSA]`

Answer (score 1):

ok here's my code (no redirect) based on [wikipedia's private network list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^172\.[1-3]{1}\d{1}\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.
RewriteRule ^index\.php index_internal.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Nice idea! Beware though: not all that's in private range must be necessarily inside your network - for example, I've seen configs where 10.1.255.255 was internal network and 10.4.255.255 was another, less trusted network via VPN. I'd allow only as much access as is necessary.

Comment: i only need to detect if my web application is accessed via public or internally just to set some constants especially redirection host for our single sign on app