# .htaccess - load specific content depending on user IP

Tags: .htaccess

On my server I have a two directories, both with php/css/jpg/png files. One directory is named `devel` and the second is `release`. Both directories contains the same page, but with different version. `release` is used to expose stable content it to a customer, and `devel` is my working directory. Right now, both pages are available through addresses like: `http://example.com/devel/index.php` and `http://example.com/release/index.php`.

Is it is possible to have an .htaccess file which for a request like `http://example.com/index.php` will load `http://example.com/devel/index.php` when users IP is `123.123.123.123` and `http://example.com/release/index.php` otherwise?

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# Enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

# Force non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/ [L,R=301]

# For not specified files extensions redirect to Entry.php
RewriteRule !^.*\.(css|js|jpg|png)$ Entry.php

# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess request forwarding if internal ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258680/htaccess-request-forwarding-if-internal-ip)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'll check it and remove the post if it does what I am looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is something different